# Finite categories with a monoidal product

Tags: category-theory

Are there categories out there with finitely many objects but that still support a symmetric monoidal product between objects and and also between morphisms?  I am thinking of some kind of modular product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with any symmetric monoidal category you like, and restrict to the full subcategory on the objects that are invertible (the "Picard category"). This subcategory will sometimes have finitely many isomorphism classes of objects even if the original didn't, and so you can take a skeleton of it. For example, if $K$ is a number field, take the symmetric monoidal category $\text{Mod}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ of modules over its ring of integers; then the group of isomorphism classes of invertible objects is the ideal class group.

Answer (score 4):

Any commutative monoid $M$ can be turned into a symmetric monoidal category by letting elements of $M$ be the objects of the category and having no morphisms other than identities.  Alternatively, $M$ can also be turned into a symmetric monoidal category with one object whose endomorphisms are $M$; both the monoidal product of morphisms and composition then coincide with multiplication in $M$.  There are many other examples of symmetric monoidal categories with finitely many objects, but these are the simplest.